# Which keyword should I use: colors or colours or a combination of both?

Tags: seo, keywords

Well this might sound weird but yeah that's exactly what I want to know!

Now as per US-English colors is the right word and as per British-English colours is the right word. Here in India we follow British English and also the local trend on Google Trends suggests that colours is more searched for in the market that my site is gonna target.

Also when I went through my competitors site they are mixing both keywords colors and colours.

As we all know Google returns separate results for colors and colours.

So I am kinda confused. Should I go for mixing of both the keywords which I feel is wrong or should stick with one keyword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my opinion:

You can choose one keyword for your website, for example "colours" to follow British English word. I think having the same word on your website is good think. Using two terms in website is kind of weird for visitors (who can be confused).

However, for backlinks campaign, you can mix two terms. There will be good to change anchor text of backlinks.

Answer (score 4):

Even though Google shows different results for `colors` and `colours` it is still smart enough to know they are the same word (as evidenced by the fact pages with 'color' are returned for a search of 'colour').

The main difference in the results appears to be that exact-match domains like `colours.co.uk` show up on their respective searches.

So I would suggest simply using the spelling of the language you are targeting.