# Getting rank for keywords that I don't want to appear on my website

Tags: seo, search-engines, search-engine-indexing, keywords

One of my products has two names. One of them is what I consider correct and thus it is what I want to appear on my website. The other name is incorrect for me, so I would like to avoid it. But I know that many people will search my product using the "bad" name.

How could I get the "bad" name indexed for my site on search engines even if nobody can read it there? Of course, I want to do it "legally" so that no engine will ban my site considering it as cloaking, black hat SEO, etc...

EDIT: Having that "bad" name on my backlinks is not an option. For example I would perceive user reviews connecting my site to that word as a negative point.

Maybe having my site as a search result for that word could be negative as well, but I think it is worth it.

Comment: You have [the answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/39251/20122) of your question on the link above.

Comment: @Zistoloen Thank you. Your answer helps me, but actually I would also like to avoid having the "bad" name on my backlinks. It is not a matter of spelling or just a preference. For me, those two words are not so close. I'll add this to my post...

Comment: Ok Rober but how can you get Google to understand your site is about a keyword you want to specify nowhere?

Comment: @Zistoloen That's exactly what I'm asking...
If it was easy I wouldn't ask here ; )
It would be great something like proposing Google adding a couple of synonimes for their searches, but I don't know if they have such a feature.
I'm looking for imaginative "legal" tricks like this.
I understand that this may be on the edge of cloaking...

Comment: I don't know how to do what you want with a white hat approach. I hope users of this community will have ideas.